# Watch a set of select-elements and sum up their id's

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select

I have a list of select-elements and would like to assure that at least one of them has a value selected. I have made a small fiddle,

http://plnkr.co/edit/bLh5Gp7fsLphjX0hcLSB?p=preview

```
$scope.$watch('vm.list', function(a, b) {
  alert('changed');
});
```

where I illustrated the problem. As seen there, I can a) not make a set value to be selected, and b) there's no event firing when one of the options are changed. I would like a button to be hidden if all of the select-boxes are not having any value, hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive for this

```
<select ng-change='myScopeFunction()' ng-model="item.value" ng-options="option.id as option.title for               option in vm.options track by option.id">
  <option value>Default</option>
</select>
```

if you want use `$watch`, try this one

```
  $scope.$watch('vm.list', function(a, b) {
    alert('changed');
  },1);
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7iuw3crFpDADGvc0i1Ru?p=preview)

Comment: I'd rather like to watch the vm.list, but your suggested change did not do the trick. Feel free to give it a try in my plunker-link above, does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: Indeed, my bad. Sorry! Thanks a lot!